# I have a PNG with blue lines, a transparent background and nothing else. Is there a way in CSS to make the lines white?

Tags: image, css

I have a **png** with blue lines, a transparent background and nothing else. Is there a way in css to make the lines **white**?

Answer (score 1):

`CSS` is used to modify the appearance of `HTML`. It cannot really affect an image directly. You could use two images of the same size, and use JavaScript to switch between them.

Here's one possible way to do this:

HTML

```
<body>
  ...
  <div>
    <image id="blue-img" class="currentFrame" src="/img/blue.png" />
    <image id="white-img" class="hiddenFrame" src="/img/white.png" />
  </div>
  ...
</body>
```

CSS

```
.currentFrame {
    display: block;
}
.hiddenFrame {
    display: none;
}
```

At this point, you could use the following JavaScript to hide one image and show the other. Because the images are the same size, and appear together in the HTML DOM, it will look like the images occupy the same space.

```
function changeFrame() {
    removeClass("blue-img", "currentFrame");
    addClass("blue-img, "hiddenFrame");
    removeClass("white-img", "hiddenFrame");
    addClass("white-img", "currentFrame");
}

// Add the given class to the DOM element with the given id
function addClass(id, class) {
    ...
}

// Remove the given class from the DOM element with the given id
function removeClass(id, class) {
   ...
}
```

The implementation of `addClass` and `removeClass()` functions are left as an exercise for the reader, but it can be much easier if you use jQuery or some other DOM API library.

You could also use the `HTML5` `<canvas>` element, if you're not concerned about backwards compatibility, or if you need a transition animation. That would also involve some JavaScript coding.

Comment: It also might be possible to include multiple animation frames inside a PNG, but I have no experience with this.

Answer (score 1):

You have at least 2 ways to achieve this effect

Option 1: Use the image as a mask

Here only the transparent part of the image is used, as a mask. If you apply it on a white element, the parts not masked will be white

```css
.base {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: yellow;
 }

.test {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-mask-image: url(http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/2/2d/SRU-Logo-Transparent.png);
  -webkit-mask-size: contain;
}
```

```html
<div class="base">
  <div class="test"></div>
</div>
```

Option 2: use a filter to change the color. For instance, use brightness(100)

```css
.base {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: yellow;
 }

.test {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background-image: url(http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/2/2d/SRU-Logo-Transparent.png);
  background-size: contain;
  -webkit-filter: brightness(100);
}
```

```html
<div class="base">
  <div class="test"></div>
</div>
```

However, both options have a limited support

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the Canvas in HTML5 to create the image on user interface :-

- it will give you more clarity as the images are created using px.
- it will give you liberty to change in what every color, size you want as they are created using javascript .